# CanCan Ability in rails active_admin is can't Comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I use CanCan Ability in active_admin.I want to comment in page show.But I use CanCan is can't Add comments in show page.

This is error message:

```
You are not authorized to perform this action.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configure the `ActiveAdmin::Comment` at `ability.rb`:

```
can [:read, :create], ActiveAdmin::Comment
```

I found the answer from this seemingly unrelated page https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/597